# How can I stub out a method that was defined in a parent controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

I defined a little method named `auth_user` in the `ApplicationController` of my app. I set it as a `before_action` in my `SessionController`.

How can I stub out that `auth_user` method from the `SessionController` test?

EDIT: I'm using minitest

Answer (score 0):

it most likely should be `SessionsController` (plural), but not that it matters here.

```
allow_any_instance_of(SessionController).to receive(:auth_user).and_return(user)
```

Comment: this is `RSpec` syntax, which is not able to be used in Minitest cases.

Comment: @EUPHORAY from what I see, this answer was written **before** the OP added the ```EDIT: I'm using minitest```. But feel free to keep your downvote.